# Radius of Convergence of $(1-x)^{1/4}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, binomial-coefficients, factorial

This is my first post so I am very new to MathJax formatting - i apologize in advance for the messy formatting

This equation becomes $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(4n-5) x^n}{(4^n)n!}$$

The textbook says the ratio test would be:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left\lvert\frac{(4n-1)(4n-5)(x^{n+1})(4^n)n!}{(4n-5)(x^n)(4^{n+1})(n+1)n!}\right\rvert$$

But I thought it would be:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left\lvert\frac{(4n-1)(x^{n+1})(4^n)n!}{(4n-5)(x^n)(4^{n+1})(n+1)!}\right\rvert$$

So no extra $(4n-5)$ - but that would result in an addition $(n+1)$ in denominator (because of the expanded factorial) and the radius of convergence would now be infinite (and not $|x| < 1$ as above fraction suggests).

Thanks

Comment: That's a damn fine MathJax attempt there! I have three notes: 1. If you want the "display" maths (i.e. centred, with larger font), use `$$` instead of `$`. 2. If you want your absolute values to match the height of the expression, use `\left` and `\right`. Compare $|\frac{a^2}{b}|$ with $\left|\frac{a^2}{b}\right|$, which are produced by `$|\frac{a^2}{b}|$` and `\left|\frac{a^2}{b}\right|` respectively. 3. If you want to group things in MathJax, use curly braces { }. Writing `$4^(n+1)$` produces $4^(n+1)$, whereas `4^{n+1}` produces $4^{n+1}$.

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: OK, the problem is that the general term contains a "fractional binomial coefficient", so you should have a product of factors in the numerator $ \ 1 \ · \ (-3) \ · \ (-7) \ · \  ... \ · \ (5-4n) \ $ , as well as an alternating-sign factor $ \ (-1)^n \ $ .  That's where the extra $ \ (4n-5) \ $ in the book's ratio comes from.  Also, they wrote $ \ (n+1)! \ $ as $ \ (n+1) · n! \ $ in the denominator of the ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Your series as written obviously has an infinite radius of converges, since the denominator grows much faster than the numerator. However, this is because there is a mistake - the numerator should be $(4n-5)!.$

Answer (score 1):

The generalized binomial series is

$$ (1 \ + \ x)^p \ \ = \ \ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \   \left( \begin{array}{c} p \\ n \end{array}   \right) \ x^n  \ \ , $$

which becomes $$ (1 \ - \ x)^p \ \ = \ \ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \  (-1)^n \ \left( \begin{array}{c} p \\ n \end{array}   \right) \ x^n  \ \  $$

for the base $ \ (1 \ - \ x) \ $ .  Writing out the first few terms of the series with the fractional binomial coefficients for $ \ p \ = \ \frac14 \ $ gives us

$$ (1 \ - \ x)^{1/4} \ \ = \ \  1 \ ·  \left( \begin{array}{c} \frac14 \\ 0 \end{array}   \right) \ x^0 \ \ + \ \  -1 \ ·  \left( \begin{array}{c} \frac14 \\ 1 \end{array}   \right) \ x^1 \ \ + \ \  1 \ ·  \left( \begin{array}{c} \frac14 \\ 2 \end{array}   \right) \ x^2 \ \ + \ \  -1 \ ·  \left( \begin{array}{c} \frac14 \\ 3 \end{array}   \right) \ x^3 \ \ + \  \ldots        $$

$$ = \ \ 1 \ · \frac{  1}{0!} \ x^0 \ \ - \ \ 1 \ · \frac{  \frac14   }{1!} \ x^1 \ \ + \ \ 1 \ · \frac{ \frac14 · \left(  \frac{-3}{4}   \right)}{2!} \ x^2 \ \ - \ \ 1 \ ·\frac{   \frac14 · \left(  \frac{-3}{4}   \right) ·  \left(  \frac{-7}{4}   \right)  }{3!} \ x^3 \ \ + \  \ldots        $$

$$ = \ \ 1  \ \ - \ \  \frac{  1   }{4 \ · \ 1!} \ x^1 \ \ + \ \  \frac{ 1 · (  -3)}{4^2 \ · \ 2!} \ x^2 \ \ - \ \ \frac{ 1 · (-3) · (-7) }{4^3 \ · \ 3!} \ x^3 \ \ + \  \ldots        $$

There are various ways that people choose for writing the general term; my guess is that this author(s) for your textbook decided to leave the first two terms outside of the general summation to start it at $ \ n \ = \ 2 \ $ (this has no effect on the interval of convergence):

$$ (1 \ - \ x)^{1/4} \ \ = \ \ 1  \ \ - \ \  \frac14 \ x \ \ - \ \ 
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ \frac{3 \ · \ 7 \ · \ · \ldots \ · \ (4n-5) }{4^n \ · \ n!} \ x^n  \ \ .  $$

This is a product of factors in arithmetic progression in the numerator of the general term; that is what must be used in the Ratio Test.  Almost all of them will cancel in the calculation, but what will remain is

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \  \left\lvert \ \frac{(4[n+1]-5)(4n-5)(x^{n+1})}{4^{n+1}  \ · \ (n+1)!} \ · \ \frac{4^n \ · \ n!}{(4n-5)(x^n) } \ \right\rvert \ \ = \ \ \lim_{n\to \infty} \  \left\lvert \ \frac{(4n-1)(x)}{4  \ · \ (n+1)}  \ \right\rvert \ \ , $$

which will yield the radius of convergence $ \ R \ = \ 1 \ $ that obtains for the series representing $ \ (1 \ + \ x)^p \ $ .  [The generalized binomial series is exactly the same as you would get by deriving a Maclaurin series for these functions.]

Comment: Please do not manually put excessive spaces in your formulas. MathJax usually does its job well, automatically.